# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `leave l JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to write a sql code to join three table together but it always show

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'leave l JOIN employee e ON l.Emp_ID=e.Emp_ID JOIN department d ON e.Dept_ID= d.D' at line 1
```

Here is my code

```
<?php

include("conn.php");

SESSION_START();

$aid = $_SESSION["eid"];
$check_user=mysql_query("select * from employee where Emp_ID='$aid'");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($check_user);

$leave   = mysql_query("select * from leave");
$_GET['Leave_ID'] = $leave['Leave_ID'];
$leaveID = $_GET['Leave_ID'];
```

?>

```
<?php
        $sql  = mysql_query("select e.Emp_Fname, e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_Email, e.ContactNo_HP, e.ContactNo_Home, l.Date_Apply, l.Leave_Type, l.Leave_Start, l.Leave_End, l.Leave_Reason FROM leave l JOIN employee e ON l.Emp_ID=e.Emp_ID JOIN department d ON e.Dept_ID= d.Dept_ID where l.Leave_ID = $leaveID");


        if($sql == FALSE)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    ?>
```

Comment: Please do some debugging. You have several pieces of code here, with 3 queries. Remove some queries. check what query generates the error. Don't just dump your code here, do some investigation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LEAVE is a keyword in Standard SQL, might be the same in MySQL. Try using backticks:

```
`LEAVE`
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave is reserved MYSQL keyword ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html))
just escape your table name with ``